# Find direction of the vector

Tags: vectors

I have two points `A(1, 2)` and `B(3, 4)` and vector `AB` between them. How can I find the direction of a vector?

I do not know if direction is appropriate word here. By direction I mean following: if I will have point `C(2, 1)` then I would have to create a vector `CD` of length, say 2, with the same direction as vector `AB` and find coordinates of point `D`.

Comment: Divide by the magnitude of AB. Any unit vector defines a direction.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you explain it?

Comment: Directions are defined by unit vectors. This should make sense since vectors have magnitude and direction. Normalizing the magnitude leaves you with a direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the vector from point $\;A\;$ to point $\;B\;$ is defined to be

$$\vec{AB}:=B-A=(2,2)$$

Sometimes is useful to take direction vectors of length 1, so you may want to normalize the above:

$$\overline u:=\frac{\vec{AB}}{||\vec{AB}||}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}(2,2)=\left(\,\frac1{\sqrt2},\,\frac1{\sqrt2}\,\right)$$

so you can talk of the direction $\;\vec{AB}\;$ or the direction $\;\overline u\;$ , it just is the same. But read carefully your definitions.